# Angular js : How i can change the color of accordion active on click

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I change the color of an active accordion when I click on the glyphicon using ng-if. I have this code: I can't succeeded to do that
have you an idea please. Thanks an advance.

style.css:

```
selectionAccordion {
            &:hover, &:focus {
                color: White;
               background-color:Blue;
            }
        }
        .directive('accordion', function () {
              return {
                  restrict: 'EA',
                  replace: true,
                  transclude: true,
                  template: '<div data-ng-transclude=""></div>',
                  controller: function () {
                      var Spots = [];
                      this.Open = function (selected_Spot) {
                          angular.forEach(Spots, function (Spot) {
                              if (selected_Spot != Spot)
                                  Spot.showMe = false;
                          });
                      };
                      this.addSpot = function (Spot) {
                         Spots.push(Spot);
                      };
                  }
              };
          })
          .directive('spotcam', function () {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'EA',
                        replace: true,
                        transclude: true,
                        require: '^accordion',
                        scope: { title: '@' },
                        template: '<div>' +


          '<div class="title selectedAccordionStyle ng-if="true"><a class=" more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]"  data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>{{title}}</div>' +
                    '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>' +
                        '</div>',
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs, accordionController) 
                            scope.showMe = false;
                            accordionController.addSpot(scope);
                            scope.toggle = function () {
                                scope.showMe = !scope.showMe;
                                accordionController.Open(scope);
                        } }  }
         });
```

thanks an advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same condition as on the nested a-tag which checks if the accordion is selected by the value showMe.

```
template: '<div>' +
          '<div class="title" ng-class="{true: \'selectedAccordionStyle\', false:\'\'}[showMe]"><a class=" more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]" data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>{{title}}</div>' +
          '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>' +
          '</div>',
```

Comment: marcus i have this class css :
.accordion>.title{ 

    background: Gray;
    color: Blue;
    padding: 10px;
    margin : 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

     &:hover, &:focus {
        color: White;
        background-color: Blue;
        & > a{
        color: White;
        background-color: Blue;
        }
    }

Comment: @sani add the class selectedAccordionStyle to the css. for example  selectedAccordionStyle { background-color: Pink; }

Comment: i want when i click  on <a> i change and fix color of div

Comment: marcus he don't change the color have you an idea pease why he do not work

Comment: excuse me marcus , can i make thecode of template in partial view "SpotTemplate" and call him in my attribute template how can i do that please:
exemple ; templateUrl : 'SpotTemplate',

Comment: I do that but he don't work for me
template: '<div>' +
                 '<div class="title" ng-class="{true: \'blue\',false:\'\'}[showMe]"><a class=" more-less glyphicon glyphicon-plus" ng-class="{true: \'glyphicon glyphicon-minus\', false:\'glyphicon glyphicon-plus\'}[showMe]"  data-ng-click="toggle()"></a>{{title}}</div>' +
                '<div class="body" data-ng-show="showMe" data-ng-transclude=""></div>' +
                '</div>',

Comment: @sani Hi again, sorry for late replay- was away for lunch! great that it worked out

Comment: not problem yes marcus  excuse me for all this question  and thank you very much can  i please read the new ticket about change content on click button please

Comment: just a last question because i must correct them please have you an idea marcus about the last tickets

Comment: hello markus how are you :) i need your help please if you are free

Comment: @sani Hi, how can i help?

Comment: i have a ticket  i need help to change content when i recieve data from json can i speak on tchat?

Comment: i opened a ticket about change content can you see him please markus :)

Comment: hello marcus can i tchat with you please